# OpenGL - Texturing a basic cube

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to texture a cube by using only one texture, but only rendering one part of it on each face.

This is the texture I wanted to use for now:

[image]

My goal is to get this done via the shaders, I'm not experienced with them yet but I'm trying my best to learn..

Here's my current fragment shader:

```
uniform sampler2D tex0;

void main()
{
    vec2 pos = vec2(gl_TexCoord[0] / 4.0);
    vec3 test = texture2D(tex0,pos).rgb;
    gl_FragColor.rgb = test;
}
```

**Obviously it's just the beginning and all of the sides are using the same part of the texture,
I'm just new to shaders and I'm not even sure if this really can be done this way..**

I just have no clue if it's really possible to determine which face I'm currently on and such, I thought I might be able to pass information about the vertex to the fragment shader and then act according to it?

P.S:
I went for this in the first place because I want a functionality where if the cube will be resized, the texture on every side will repeat itself rather than stretch

Answer (score 0):

`gl_TexCoord` is deprecated. You should create another general-purpose vertex attribute and store texture coordinates in it.

While applying texture is done in fragment shader, texture coordinates are usually supplied to vertex shader first and then interpolated in it linearly across all generated fragments:

```
#version 430
//...
layout(location = 1) in vec2 attr_texcoord;
out vec2 out_texcoord;

void main () {
    out_texcoord = attr_texcoord;
    //...
}
```

Now you can use `out_texcoord` in fragment shader.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, is it possible for you to explain a bit further how I'd actually know what face I'm currently on though? also, how would I be able to offset the texture to display other parts of it? because at the moment the cube I got only shows the "top" part of the texture and no matter what I do, I don't see a good way of getting it to display other parts

Comment: Did you understand the sentence "create another general-purpose vertex attribute and store texture coordinates in it."?

Comment: I guess I haven't? what did I miss? ;x

Comment: How can *I* know what *you* didn't understand exactly? I suggest [reading this](http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut) first (the first few chapters).

Comment: Alrighty, though I think I understand what you mean now. correct me if I'm wrong, but add an attribute to each vertex while creating a mesh? and that attribute will hold the xyz locations?

Comment: The texture coordinate attributes usually hold `u` and `v`, as they are *usually* called, at least for 2D textures.

Comment: I see, alrighty then I guess I'm gonna have to give it a read now.. thanks anyway for now, but just out of curiosity - will this approach allow me to repeat one part of a texture on every side of the cube rather than stretching it?

Comment: May I ask you if you have any idea how to generate uv map on a cube mesh that I create during runtime? because I really can't find any information about that..

Comment: @Don perhaps you can join me [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27957/explaining-opengl)